# Circle shape height and width issues in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-shape

I created an Oval Shape and set the sizes 56px for each height and width. but i had an Oval Shape not a circle! when i set the sizes to 78px for each i get an exact circle! Anyone noticed or faced this issue? 
Solutions please!

clear_test.xml this gives me an Oval shape! different Height and Width in the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#7caf00"/>
    <size android:width="56px"
        android:height="56px"/>

</shape>
```

calc_test.xml But this gives an exact circle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#7caf00"/>
    <size android:width="78px"
        android:height="78px"/>



</shape>
```

Comment: post code for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Shape depends upon the size of your view.The view on which you are setting this shape drawable should have equal sizes

for eg:

```
<view android:layout_width="56px" android:layout_height="56px" android:background="@drawable/clear_test"/>
```

Note:
You shouldn't use px, always use dp/dip as measurement units.(Above example has "px",so it does match your xml code)

Comment: It works fine! but i'm supporting multiple screens so i will need bigger shapes for bigger screens! i set height and width wrap_content.
and why does it work when the sizes are 78px! weird..

Comment: what kind of view are you using, imageview,textview ?

Comment: Since you have to support multiple screen, it's better to set the size of your view by code, because wrap_content may give rect shape instead of square shape